# Problems migrating git repository server without access to original

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I know this has been asked, but I couldn't seem to implement any of the solutions and I'm a bit confused.

I have two websites hosted on AWS EC2.  They are written in node.js using express, css, jQuery, MongoDB, etc.  The git repository server was the original developers computer.

When I ssh into one of the sites through bash and

```
vi website/.git/config
```

It contains:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@oldurl.org:website.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

The website also has a staging.website.com which I have separate ssh access to.  The config file in staging.website.com website/.git/config contains:

```
[core]
    ""
    logallrefupdates = true
    ""
```

And the rest the same.

I have the source code for the websites, the login for AWS, ssh access to both servers.  I want to set up a new repository server on either my Synology DS213 or a virtualized instance running off one of our servers.  What I don't have is access to the original computer that hosted the git repository. "oldurl.org"  What is the easiest/best way to go about creating a new hosted repository so that I can work on the site on my local PC, commit changes to the repository server, and then push them out from there to my EC2's.  Whenever I try to setup a new repo locally and add the remote the the server, on all my tests I couldn't get the files I created locally to upload to the server.  Does it only change files and not create new ones if they are only added locally?  For the record I have a ~/.ssh/config file set up for the rsa keys.  Essentially I want to take the place of git@oldurl.com  How would I go about doing that?

EDIT: One thing I've had a bit of trouble understanding is the difference between site/.git and site.git

If you need any more specifics or information please let me know.  I'm eager to get this fixed so I can once again safely make changes to my websites.  The original developer is no longer managing them and cannot be contacted for assistance.

Comment: My git fu isnt as strong as i'd like. But you should be able to change the config with a new remote to an empty repository and then just run `git push remote`. Unlike SVN, all git 'working copies' are repositories in themselves.

Comment: `site/.git` is a git repo with a working tree checked out in it. `site.git` is [a bare repo](http://gitolite.com/concepts/bare.html), usually used for pushing to it, because there is no working tree to update/maintain after the push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by doing

```
git remote remove origin
```

and

```
git remote add origin newurrl
```

Comment: No problem. I have deleted my previous comment, and will delete this one today.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to apply a similar fix is:

```
git remote set-url origin newurrl
```

See [`git remote` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote set-url' <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
```

> Changes URL remote points to.
>   Sets first URL remote points to matching regex `<oldurl>` (first URL if no `<oldurl>` is given) to `<newurl>`.
>   If `<oldurl>` doesn’t match any URL, error occurs and nothing is changed.